# read tags from UITextfield in UITableview at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield

I have a tableview that has a tableViewCell.

Each cell has a textfield and i have a button outside the tableView.

I need when i write in one or all the textFields and tap a button i want to print tags of the textFields that have values but in the same time.

I succeeded to print individual tag for each of them.

```
    private var currentTextField: UITextField?
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        currentTextField = textField
    }
@IBAction func submitChangesBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if let currentText = currentTextField,
           let tag = currentTextField?.tag {
            currentText.resignFirstResponder()
             print("tag: \(tag)")
        }

        currentTextField?.text = ""

    }
```

but i want to print them all at the same time [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjKub.png)

this is my tableView content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could store all edited textFields in array of UITextFields (or Ints if you don't need the UITextField objects but only the tags), something like this:

```
private var currentTextFields: [UITextField] = []
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if !currentTextFields.contains(textField) { // avoid duplicates
        currentTextFields.append(textField)
    }
}
@IBAction func submitChangesBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    var tagString = ""
    for tf in currentTextFields {
        tf.text = ""
        tagString = "\(tagStirng) \(tf.tag)"
    }
    print("all tags: \(tagString)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through `UITableView` to get all `UITableViewCell` from it, after it can get `UITextField` object from `UITableViewCell`.

```
@IBAction func submitChangesBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    for i in 0...self.tableView.numberOfSections-1
    {
        for j in 0...self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: i)-1
        {

            if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: j, section: i)) {

                for view in cell.subviews{
                    if let textfield = view as? UITextField{
                        print("tag: \(textfield.tag)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like the following.

```
@IBAction func submitChangesBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let totalCell: Int = 5
    for row in 0..<totalCell {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

        for view in (cell?.contentView.subviews)! {
            if let textField = view as? UITextField {
                print("tag: \(textField.tag)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, why do you need to do this? Anyway It would be great if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all table view rows.

   2. Get textfield from cell.
   3. Print all textfield tag.